# Running JavaScript Code in REPL vs Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, console, read-eval-print-loop

So i've begun learning about JavaScript through the book JavaScript Allonge. But the thing is the output of the code differs from when I enter it in on Sublime Text and when I enter it in on REPL online which it asks me to put the code.

```
((PI) =>
  ((PI) =>
    (diameter) => diameter * PI
  )(3.14159265)
)(3)(2)
//=> 6.2831853
```

for example that doesn't not give the same output as when I put it in Sublime Text.

```
(n) => {
const even = (x) => {
if (x === 0) return true;
else {
const odd = (y) => !even(y);
return odd(x - 1); }
}
return even(n) }
```

This is also another piece of code that not only doesn't compile but doesn't make sense either. How would an Arg n input to the x or y values?

Is there a way to get the true JavaScript output offline?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What output *does* Sublime give? And what compile error?

Comment: "*How would an Arg n input to the x or y values?*" - in the `even(n)` call at the end of the function.